# Is React.lazy callback guaranteed to be run only once?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is `React.lazy` callback guaranteed to be run only once?

Use-case is injecting RTK & RTKQ endpoints, e.g:

```js
const Component = React.lazy(() => {
    injectApi(componentApi)
    injectStore(componentStore)
    return import('component-path')
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy 

> This will automatically load the bundle containing the OtherComponent when this component is **first rendered**.

Comment: Yes, but is it guarantied that it will not run more than once and is it safe to handle additional logic in that callback?

Answer (score 1):

At least for the RTKQ part, you are probably just overthinking it.

Follow the [RTKQ Code Splitting guidance](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting): create one empty api for everything and add that to your store from the start, then use `injectEndpoints` in various other files to add endpoints to it. From these files, export the hooks.

When you import those hooks from a file that is code-split, the file will be included and the endpoints will be injected into your api. If you never import one of those hooks, it will never happen. You don't need to write any manual logic for that.